# Angular modules with subroutes and navbar

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have an application that is seperated into the following modules:

```
/app
    /core
    /admin
    /authentication
    /wst
```

Admin is a complex module with sidebar and authentication is just a login screen. I want to load the sidebar only when the admin module is active and I don't want to include it in the app.component.html with an *ngIf.

How can I make such a configuration to work?
I'm using Angular7, and started a [stackblitz that shows my problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqsrf5).

- If I add router-outlet to app.component.html, that eg. /login route works 
  fine.
- If I try the same with /admin nothing shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want ProfileComponent inside AdminComponent, routing for AdminModule should be something like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent }
    ]
  },
]
```

There are also some build errors to be fixed first:

- Import AdminRoutingModule instead of RoutingModule in AdminModule.
- The ProfileComponent should be either declared or imported in AdminModule.

Then `/admin/profile` should show the AdminComponent with menu and profile. If you want it to be `/admin`, just add redirection rules to the routes.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast!